# A symmetry identity involving norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $x,y\ne 0$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Give a geometrical interpretation of the identity

$\Big \Vert\frac {x}{\Vert x\Vert} -\Vert x\Vert y\Big \Vert =  
\Big \Vert\frac {y}{\Vert y\Vert} -\Vert y\Vert x\Big \Vert $.

Here $\Vert\cdot\Vert $ denotes the Euclidean norm. I can prove the identity algebraically; both sides are $1-2\langle x,y\rangle +\Vert x\Vert^2+\Vert y\Vert^2$. What is a geometrical interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=x/\|x\|,\ v=y/\|y\|$ and $p=\|x\|\|y\|$. The identity can then be rewritten as
$$
\|u-pv\|=\|v-pu\|.
$$
It's true simply because there exists a linear isometry $Q$ such that $Qu=v$ and $Qv=u$.

Comment: Can you please explain why this identity is implied by the existence of Q?

Comment: @Shahab $u-pv=Q(v-pu)$.

Comment: Thank you. How can we prove that Q always exists?

Comment: @Shahab Let $V=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$. Simply define $Q|_V$ as the reflection about $u+v$ (i.e. define $Q(u+v):=u+v$ and $Q(u-v):=v-u$) and $Q|_{V^\perp}$ as the identity map.