# Ptolemy's inequality for Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, triangle-inequality

I'm trying to prove that this inequality holds for all $x, y, z, t \in H$ (H is some Hilbert space):

$\|x-z\|*\|y-t\|\leq \|x-y\|*\|z-t\|+\|y-z\|*\|x-t\|$

My approach is as follows:
For all zero vectors it's obvious. Let's assume that none of vectors are zero, then let's make substitution:

$x'=\displaystyle{\frac{x}{\|x\|^{2}}}, t'=\displaystyle{\frac{t}{\|t\|^{2}}}, z'=\displaystyle{\frac{z}{\|z\|^{2}}}$  Let's apply triangle inequality to $\|z'-x'\|:$

$\|z'-x'\|\le\|z'-t'\|+\|t'-x'\| -> \displaystyle{\frac{\|z-x\|}{\|z\|*\|x\|}}\le\displaystyle{\frac{\|z-t\|}{\|z\|*\|t\|}}+\displaystyle{\frac{\|t-x\|}{\|t\|*\|x\|}}$  multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\|z\|*\|x\|*\|y\|*\|t\|$ gives us

$\|z-x\|*\|y\|*\|t\|\le\|z-t\|*\|x\|*\|y\|+\|t-x\|*\|y\|*\|z\|$ and that's the part when I'm stuck.

I have an idea, to show that $\|y-t\|\le\|y\|+\|t\|\le\|y\|*\|t\|$ , but it seems incorrect (at least I don't know any useful inequalities to say that it's true).

Comment: Do you know how to prove Ptolemy's inequality in 2-D Euclidean space first? If yes, can you modify it to a Hilbert space?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988786/norm-inequality-x-y-cdot-z-leq-x-z-cdot-y-z