# Polarization identity for normed space satisfying Ptolemy's inequality

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality#Inner_product_spaces) article states that a normed space $(H,\rVert \cdot \lVert)$ where
$$
\lVert x-y \rVert \lVert z \rVert + \lVert y-z \rVert \lVert x \rVert \geq \lVert x-z \rVert \lVert y \rVert 
$$
for all $x,y,z \in H$ has a unique inner product inducing the norm $\rVert \cdot \lVert.$ How do you prove this fact?

I guess that the fact that the inequality
$$
\lVert x+y \rVert ^2 + \lVert x-y \rVert ^2 \le 2\lVert x \rVert ^2 + 2 \lVert y \rVert ^2
$$
for all $x,y \in H$ implies the parallelogram law might help, though I'm not sure.

Comment: You may consult the source https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1967.11975804?journalCode=umma20

Comment: See also this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988786/121671) in MSE

Comment: The characterization of normed spaces which satisfies Ptolomy's inequality is [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-06/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9.pdf)